# Setting a custom class for a SKLabelNode in SpriteKit scene editor?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I have a class PrettyLabel which is a subclass of SKLabelNode class. How can I set this as a custom class for a node which is a SKLabelNode in spritekit scene editor in .sks file? Is it possible? For SKSpriteNode there is an option named custom class in right inspector panel however I cannot find anything like that if the node is a SKLabelNode. Is there any way to set this custom class for a label node in scene editor or it is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add it as a SKNode, then set the custom class and work with it programmatically.